# QueryDSL is not returning the object

Tags: java, spring-data, querydsl

I'm having a problem with query dsl. I have generated the querydsl classes. But when I try to do a query, it is not returning a result object of type Customer, but rather it is returning the actual sql query. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(App.class);
        CustomerRepository repository  = context.getBean(CustomerRepository.class);

        repository.save(new Customer("Alicia", "Keys"));

        QCustomer customer = QCustomer.customer;
        EntityManager em = context.getBean(EntityManager.class);
        JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(em);

        Customer alicia = query.from(customer).where(customer.id.eq(1L));

        context.close();

}
```

}

Comment: That code doesn't even compile, `where(…)` doesn't return a `Customer`, but a Querydsl type.

Comment: I created the QueryDSL types before doing the actual query. But when I tried to write the query, yes, I was getting syntax errors because of the type issue. It was fixed by the adding uniqueResult.

Comment: Awesome, great to hear it now works for you! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you miss `uniqueResult` (or `list()` for multiple results)

```
query.from(customer)
   .where(XXX)
   .uniqueResult(customer);
```

See : http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/2.1.0/reference/html/ch02.html